# How to change visibility of ALL items in a JFrame at once?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, visibility

I wonder whether there is a possiblity to change the visibility of more than one item (textbox, button, chart ...) in a `JFrame` in one simple(?) command.

Thanks for answers and ideas!

(Hiding the whole `JFrame` is no option ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]

Obviously, one of the two panels shown in the demo would have no components.

Answer (score 3):

Place all into a panel and hide/show the panel. That should propagate to all child components as well

Answer (score 2):

Place components into Collection, then you can use simple iteration to set/clear any flags. You need to create a Collection and add objects to it, but this allows to separate visibility control from the component layout.